# How can i manage dependecy of JavaFX project with m2Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, m2eclipse

JavaFX Editor in Eclipse couldn't see dependencies which is imported by m2eclipse (Junit,  JavaFX library..), i must put libraries from Project Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries, if i want to solve this problem.

**M2Eclipse plugin and JavaFX plugin couldn't work together?**  OR **JavaFX plugin couldn't work with Eclipse successfully ???**